# Use txt.split() with multiple delimiters in Schematiq

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a more elegant way to perform the following function `=txt.Split(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",";"),";")`? The `txt.Split(str,delimiter)` function is a Schematiq function that tokensises strings based on a single delimiter.

I have a file delimited by a large number of different separators (about ten in total) and I want to avoid nesting `SUBSTITUTE` functions and create a `rng` of these tokens.

eg for Cell A1 contents : `The,quick;brown#fox` I would want a `rng` returning of 4 elements that are:

`The`

`quick`

`brown`

`fox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt.Split` supports both multi-character delimiters and also multiple delimiters, so if you tried to do this as:

```
=txt.Split("The,quick;brown#fox", ",;#")
```

...you would just get a single cell range back because the string ",;#" is not present in "The,quick;brown#fox". However, if instead you use:

```
=txt.Split("The,quick;brown#fox", {",", ";", "#"})
```

...you will get what you're asking for. Similarly, you can use a cell reference for the delimiters, so if you put ",", ";" and "#" in cells A1, A2 and A3, you could get the same result with:

```
=txt.Split("The,quick;brown#fox", A1:A3)
```